# Spring Boot app Eureka UI not displayed properly

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I have setup a spring boot application with Netflix Eureka.
It works functionally well without any issues. But the Eureka UI is not displayed properly. 
I checked the dependencies and also for any errors but I dont see any. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you show your dependency for eureka server, main application class, and configurations. Also open dev-console in your browser, and look at some errors on client side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server` do you use? Try the `Greenwich` release.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```